# Is $\aleph_1\cdot\mathfrak c=2^\mathfrak c$ consistent with ZF?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This is something I couldn't figure out while answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106995/value-of-the-cardinal-product-aleph-1-cdot-mathfrakc). I know that $\aleph_1\lt2^\mathfrak c$ and $\mathfrak c\lt2^\mathfrak c$, whence it follows that $\aleph_1\cdot\mathfrak c\le2^\mathfrak c$, but I didn't see how to prove the strict inequality $\aleph_1\cdot\mathfrak c\lt2^\mathfrak c$ without the axiom of choice.

Is $\aleph_1\cdot\mathfrak c=2^\mathfrak c$ consistent with ZF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite literally.

Since there is a surjection from $\Bbb R$ onto $\omega_1$, there is one from $\Bbb R$ onto $\omega_1\times\Bbb R$.

In particular, $\omega_1\times\Bbb R$ cannot be in bijection with $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$, as the latter has no surjection from $\Bbb R$ itself.

Comment: Oh, right. Thank you. But why "not quite literally" instead of just plain "no"?

Comment: Because I think one can arrange that $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ is an $\aleph_1$-union of sets of size $\Bbb R$. If I had to guess, I'd say that starting with a model of GCH and doing a Feferman–Levy style construction with collapsing $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ to be $\omega_2$ should have the wanted result.